# Views Exposed form in block : how to add a ajax results counter?

Tags: ajax, views, blocks

I implemented a view as following :

- a page display with an extensive exposed filters form (Better exposed filters), ajax enabled, let's call it the landing page
- a clone of it, in a second page display with exactly the same fields, but few exposed filters instead (quick search form)
- that clone has exactly the same path, **Exposed form in block is set to yes**

I display the clone created block (quick search form) on homepage : submitting its form redirects to landing page with correct results and the complete exposed filters. This is fine.

### Question :

I need to display **a results count** next to the exposed form block, **which refreshes each time** you change a exposed filter value in the form.

The **Global: Result summary** in header or footer doesn't work because  footer and header aren't displayed together with the exposed block, they only come with the full view display.

How could solve that, either with UI or programmatically ? Below some ideas to begin, there might be a good and straight way :

- force the results count header to be displayed next to exposed block ?
- add a markup to the form with ajax results ?
- create another block ?

### EDIT

I tried several approaches based on Shreya answer below, but the blocking point is always the same, I need to execute the view to get result count, but as soon as I do, it returns an *Allowed memory size exhausted*.

in template.php :

```
function shoot_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars){

  if($vars['form']['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-customer-products-list-search-block') {
    $view = views_get_view('MY_VIEW');
    $view->set_display('MY_DISPLAY');
    $view->execute();
    $count = count( $view->result );
    $vars['count'] = $count;
  }
}
```

in views-exposed-form--MY_VIEW.tpl.php

```
print 'There are:'. $count. 'results';
```

And other tries with `views_get_current_view()` or `views_get_view_result()` in the tpl, also tried within form alter :

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-view-my-display') {
    $view = views_get_view('MY_VIEW');
    $view->set_display('MY_DISPLAY');
    $view->get_total_rows = true; 
    $view->pre_execute(); 
    $view->preview('MY_DISPLAY');
    $view->execute(); 
    $content = $view->total_rows; 
  }
  $form['submit']['#value'] = 'Voir les'. $content.' résultats';
}
```

Any clue to explain why I can't execute the view, or how to return count in that context ?

Comment: you can alter the the exposed form tpl and print the total count

Comment: Next to exposed form block means ..before the views results are displayed ..am i correct

Comment: Yes, I want to display a result counter next to exposed form, before submitting and redirecting to results page. Counter refreshed whenever any exposed filter is changed...

Comment: $view = views_get_view('my_view'); $view->set_display("page_1"); ///$view->set_arguments($er); $view->get_total_rows = true; $view->pre_execute(); $view->execute(); $content = $view->total_rows; $form['mymodule'] = array( '#type' => 'textfield', '#title' => t('title'), '#value' => $content, ); this works – Use form alter

Comment: @Shreya, tks but if I understand your proposal, it doesn't work. Wherever I execute the view in exposed block context, it ends with a memory size exceeded. And I try with a very very simple basic view and few results for dev purpose. Please edit your answer to expose the last solution you think is working

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a folder structure as sites/all/themes/example_theme/templates/views

2.Create a file named views-exposed-form.vars where you use MYTHEME_preprocess_views_exposed_form. Code snippet below:

```
function example_theme_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars){
  if($vars['form']['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-exaample-page') {
    $views_rows = views_get_view_result('my_custom_view', 'page');
$count_rows = count($views_rows);
   $vars['count'] = $count_rows;
  }

}
```

3. Then you can override the exposed filter tpl. To override the
   exposed form template for a particular view, you need to create a
   template in the following name pattern,

   **views-exposed-form--view_name.tpl.php**

   and print the $count variable wherever you want to place the count.
   Once you add the template clear the cache.

Comment: Did you try this?? And keep use ajax to Yes

Comment: Yes I tried this pm, thanks for your answer. First, I had never heard of .vars files before (assuming  `.vars.php`). Googling gives results almost especifically in [Bootstrap context](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!registry!README.md/7#theme-preprocess) . I tried anyway, but the code isn't processed.

Comment: So I tried to put that function in `template.php`. Then another problem is, you can count rows of any display of the view except for the currently exposed block, it returns memory fatal error. I made extensive tries, changing the display with exposed form block but it's always the same. you can't execute and count the one exposed.

Comment: $view = views_get_current_view() did you try this

Comment: No, but I tried `$view = views_get_view('customer_products_list');
    $view->set_display('partir');
    $view->execute();
    $count = count( $view->result );` and it gives same error when I execute the view. What about the .vars.php file first please ?

Comment: I've just tried `views_get_current_view()` but in that context it s not a vierw context and returns no view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39297/discussion-between-shreya-shetty-and-kojo).

Answer (score 0):

You could try a front-end approach.
In the views header you can show the total results (Global: Result Summary) in a hidden div and, using js, take the value from there and print it wherever you want.

> Edit: I misuderstood your implemmentation. You could try using a block
>   with exactly the same filters (hidden with css) you need, showing
>   nothing but a header. You can adjust it
>   to work with ajax, so the results will be refreshed and use js to
>   change the filters with those changed in the exposed form in the
>   block.

Comment: well as explained in question me the header is not showing up With an exposed form block display. No html output.

Comment: I've got many views with exposed forms in blocks and that doesn't have any effect in headers appearing or not. You could try using mefibs module which kind of improves better exposed filters.

Comment: please read again my implementation. The header would appear in the main part of The View not in the exposed form block. and in order to have Xposed filters both in the block and in the target view, I have 2 displays not one. i'll have a look at that module but I would prefer coding because I already have a bunch of modules, this might be an overkill. Thank you

Comment: sorry, I changed my answer. I hope it can help.